# I'm using R to create a time series - having some difficulty understanding frequency

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working with a dataset of electrical submeter readings taken once per minute for 47 months. I'm trying to create a time series that covers meter readings from the kitchen during the week of January 21-27, 2007. My code at the moment is as follows:

```
myWeek <- filter(hpc_by_datetime, "2007-01-21 00:00:00" <= DateTime &    DateTime < "2007-01-28 00:00:00")


#Create Time Series
kitchenweek <- ts(myWeek$submeter_kitchen, frequency = 525600, start = c(2007, 28800))
```

What would be a reasonable *frequency* to use in this situation? And is the vector I assign to *start* affected by this?

Comment: Your principal seasonality is going to be daily -- the kitchen will have peaks around mealtime, closed during the night, etc. So I would use the number of minutes in a day, 1440.  Now, in R, some packages won't handle all frequencies (e.g. Hyndman's auto arima in the Forecasting package).  You might also consider collapsing by hour (and use 24) or by quarter hour (and use 96).

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit difficult to answer your question here is my best try. Frequency in this definition is nothing other than the rate of occurrence. The frequency has an inverse relationship to the period. For example say the frequency of an event is 60. This means that the event will happen 60 times a minute, the period is then nothing other than 1/60 or that once every seconds an event will occur.

In your case and since mentioned the use of senors I am assuming that these data sensors are connected to a micro controller. Similar to your computer's GHz micro-controllers also have a baud rate, which is simply how fast the internal clock is ticking. The baud rate is the rate that the information is transferred to the device. If my assumption is correct you need to determine the speed at which your device operates, and set the baud rate (or frequency) to mathematically be set to the once per minute requirement.

9600 is a typical baud rate. This means that 9600 bits are sent per second, or every 1/9600 one bit is sent across the communication channel.

Set your frequency / baud rate to the proper value assuming my 9600 assumption, and size of your data reading.

Google baud rate equations, determine the data bus speed, and solve for the correct value given the conditions.

I hope this helped!